# Which would win in a battle between a Mon Calamari star cruiser and an Imperial Star Destroyer?

Tags: star-wars

It is often seen in major *Star Wars* space battles that rebel fleets, containing Mon Calamari star cruisers, fight Imperial star destroyers. However, its appears (from my perception) that both can be (relatively) easily destroyed by other smaller star fighters, such as X-Wings or TIE fighters (or at least depicted in *Star Wars Rebels* and at the Battle of Endor.)

My question is this: **Which would win between a Mon Calamari star cruiser and an Imperial Star Destroyer, taking into account if it was a single ship-on-ship battle?** For the sake of adding detail, I am specifying that the Mon Calamari star cruiser would be a [MC80 star cruiser](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/MC80_star_cruiser) and the Imperial Star Destroyer would be a [Imperial II-class Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_II-class_Star_Destroyer).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U9pdc8SbYQ

Comment: I feel like this is bordering on Gorilla vs. Shark, namely that we can do little but speculate.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It's directly answerable and both ships are seen in the same fictional universe. This is gorilla vs. gorilla (or possibly shark vs. shark)

Comment: @Valorum: {nods} As long as it's not dependent on where they meet, and we're not basing it off of a small sample size, I suppose there is an answer. Maybe consider it under "Who would win, a European knight or a samurai?" kind of question?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Any "who would win" question is borderline opinion-based, including your example, unless the parties actually fought. In this context, walrus vs polar bear is opinion based as strong walruses escape to water and polar bear never attacks strong members of the herd but lion vs tiger is answerable because Romans sparred them a lot to have an answer.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Sure, there's always going to be a certain element of luck involved (q.v. David vs. Goliath) but that doesn't mean we can't directly compare the relative strengths of items seen in the same universe, **especially when we have an authoritative source to describe their strengths.**

Comment: I'm voting for reopening, as we have sources that compare the two (claiming them to be "equal", or "close", as well as tech manuals with an exact number of weapons, fighter capacity, speed, agility and shielding technology.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Cruiser-nado. This time, it's a trap!

Comment: we already have seen that a single A-Wing can take out a super star destroyer, so surely the a heavy Mon Cal crusier stands a chance ;) - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Executor

Comment: ***WHICH*** Star Destroyer? There's like 5 (if not 20) versions; vastly different in capabilities.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is addressed in [The Official Star Wars Fact File #12](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_12). In short, the M80 Mon Calamari Cruiser is considered to be *nearly* comparable to a Star Destroyer. They'd need luck to win in a straight one-on-one fight.

[image]

<sub><sup>*"The powerful MC80 considerably evened the odds for the Rebellion, as the Mon Calamari star cruiser was virtually on a par with the Imperial Star Destroyers"*.</sup></sub>